# FB graph API get post comments by given user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Do you know if its possible to get the list of post comments by given user?

I tried this: `<post_id>/comments?fields=from.id(<user_id>)` but it still returns array of **all** post comments. I think I have enabled all the permissions because I can see the `from` field but it looks like 1) the filter is not working, 2) I am doing it wrong. The graph API version I am using is `v9.0`

My goal is to get list of comments by given user or receive an empty array if the user didnt comment the post. Maybe there is a different way how to do it..

Comment: No, there is no way to do that, they API does not offer that kind of filtering capabilities.

Comment: :-( ok nevermind, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Why is it still possible for Instagram but not for Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this by calling the graph api anymore :/

But, there is some kind of workaround you may be able to do.

First, you'll have to set a page webhook to retrieve all the comments written on your page. Find the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime

The information sent to your server via the new comment's webhook contains the "from" data, looking like this:

```
{
    name: "Foo Bar",   // the user's name
    id: "12345"  // A user ID (unique for your page. Will be different for the same user accross 2 different pages)
}
```

You may then be able to pick only the wanted user's comment

I clearly see 3 downsides to this workaround:

- It only works with pages
- You need to handle in realtime all the comments written on your page
- You cannot retrieve the comments posted in the past

Comment: Wow! sounds great! do you know if it's possible to receive a webhook when comment is changed or deleted?

Comment: Yes the same webhook is fired when comment is updated. You can check `verb` of the entry data. It can be either "add", "update" or even "hide" for an hidden comment. I cannot find the documentation on this I'm sorry.